nginx page displaying instead of home page
I'm using Docker to serve an Angular application using Nginx. However, when I access my application at http://localhost:8080/, I'm seeing the default Nginx welcome page instead of my Angular application's home page. I've checked that my Angular application is built and deployed correctly, but Nginx is not serving it as expected.


http {
    server {

        listen 80;
        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index index.html;
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

        }

        # Handle JavaScript | CSS files with the correct MIME type
        location ~ \.(js|css)$ {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        }

        # Catch-all location to handle refreshes on any route
        location ~ ^/.+$ {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index index.html;
            try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
    }




Please share the folder structure that gets deployed to the server, where in that structure is the angular app index.html placed?

Check if /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html exists in the container,this is built by angular.

yes it's exist in the container , and the container is running
